# Filtering and sanitizing ints and floats - Can I just add zero?

Tags: php, numbers, sanitization

I'm using PHP, I've read various posts on sanitizing/filtering and am happy with how I both save and read/represent my data.

But... When it comes to numeric data, my filtering/sanitizing deleted the decimal point.

As a solution, can I not have the server just do a computation on the client data and add zero to the value sent? This implies if the user/client was to send the server non-numeric (perhaps some sql injection string), their ill intent would fail as my string would result in zero.

Acceptable or no? Can anyone forsee a weakness in this?

I ask because I have tried to use

```
$str=filter_var( $str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT );
```

and it removed the decimal point. By adding a zero, I can ensure decimal place is kept.

(thanks in advance)

Comment: can you give an example of whats being removed as it sounds like this for example `2.` becomes `2`

Comment: 1.9 becomes 19 when I use the filter.

I know there are filter flags I could pass but I guess I misunderstand their usage as my results have varied when I tried to use it in the past. So I thought a cheaper solution would be just to add zero.

Comment: This may be of help then, http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_sanitize_number_float.asp

Comment: Okay... That works... Thanks... But I still wondering if adding zero to numeric variables has any issues, since it does not call a function, I suspect it would be better on system resources. But I will roll with your suggestion. Thanks again

Comment: Resource impact should be minimal, in any case always go with readability of code over performance( except in extreme cases ) looking at the code latter ( or someone else ) will be able to tell the meaning using the built in way, whereas the reason behind adding a 0 may not be obvious to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above... Adding zero to a variable is workable and acceptable though not clear to everyone.